# Word for different office/work "cultures"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word to describe differences between two groups of professional fields.

Our small company is having a competition for best outside-of-work pictures. There are about 10 people in the San Diego, CA office, comprised of graphic designers and wordsmiths for creating brochures and such, and 10 people in the Central Oregon office that are mostly programmers/EDI developers.

I was thinking we will see big difference in the *type* of pictures submitted between the two offices because of the ______ (cultural?/demographic?/??) difference between the two professional fields.

What is a good word for that?

I suppose you can guess I am not on the wordsmith side :)

Comment: I'd say the difference would be because of the different skillsets inherent for each group.  Skillset is "nicer" than saying "talent" since skills are part talent and probably a bigger part practice and time spent honing a set of skills.

Comment: You are expecting to see a *correlation* between the type of picture an employee submits and the office to which they belong. And the wordsmith side is probably expecting to see a big difference *between* the type of pictures submitted *by* the two offices ;)

Answer (score 1):

A fairly recent buzzword that would work well for this situation is **wheelhouse**:

> We will see a big difference in the type of pictures submitted between
>   the two offices because of their different **wheelhouses**.

This is an extension of the idiom:

> **in someone's wheelhouse**
>
> (US, idiomatic) Matching a person's interests or abilities well.
>
> ([Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_someone%27s_wheelhouse))

It's a bit more flexible than some more formal options, and encompasses both skill sets and inclinations. Examples of this extended usage:

> While these three artists come from very different **wheelhouses**,
>   they share a knack for storytelling and an ear for melody. ([*The
>   Bulletin*](http://www.bendbulletin.com/entertainment/3592562-151/local-songwriters-share-their-stories-in-bend), comparing musicians from various genres)
>
> ---
>
> ARE YOU A BETTER WRITER THAN YOUR PARENTS? ;) HAHA DO THEY MAKE YOU
>   PROOFREAD FOR THEM?
>
> My parents are in computer science and medicine so our jobs are in
>   completely different **wheelhouses**. ([Aemilia Madden chat
>   transcript](http://unum.la/blog-1/2016/7/12/aemilia-meet-the-insta))
>
> ---
>
> In Elementary, Joan and Sherlock have this very interesting dynamic;
>   they have very different **wheelhouses**, but they’re equals and Joan
>   is one of the few people that really keeps up with Sherlock.
>   ([Blog](http://gladiatorofturtles.tumblr.com/post/135007657952/lindt-choclate-is-the-best-i-grew-up-in-a-town))

For a discussion of the phrase's origins, see [this Chicago Tribune article](http://articles.chicagotribune.com/2012-05-09/features/ct-tribu-words-work-wheelhouse-20120509_1_star-power-business-cruise).

Some similar, more traditional terms might be **line**, **sphere**, or **bailiwick**.

Answer (score 0):

"Culture" in business generally describes the sort of conditions that define the workplace experience (see, for example, http://www.inc.com/jt-odonnell/5-signs-your-companys-culture-is-dying.html). In this sense, *culture* refers to whether or not males wear suits and ties, or whether or not the office has an open-floor plan or cubicles, and whether or not the company organizes photo contests for its workers. In this sense, different industries are certainly characterized by different cultures (e.g., banking culture is not like media culture), but different kinds of workers within one industry (or perhaps one company) would generally be said to experience the same culture.

"Demographics" refers, especially in business, to statistical categories, often related to consumers (Tiffany's and Walmart appeal to different demographics, for example).

I think I would use a word like *sensibility*, which, per [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sensibility), is

> the kinds of feelings that a certain type of person tends to have

Other possibilities are *outlook*, *perspective*, and *world view*.

> I was thinking we'd see big difference in the type of pictures
>   submitted between the two offices because of the different
>   sensibilities that graphic designers and programmers have

or some such.

Answer (score 0):

Try [subculture](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subculture)

> A group that has beliefs and behaviors that are different/distinguishing from the main groups within a culture,group or society.

Your sentence becomes "Subcultural difference between the two professional fields."

Answer (score 0):

How about the different **mentality** of the different people?

It seems to me that it does capture your example quite nicely. "I was thinking we will see big difference in the type of pictures submitted between the two offices because of the *mentality* difference between the two professional fields."

> *mode or way of thought* [- MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mentality)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the *difference in **orientation***.

Cambridge Dictionary:

> ["orientation" in **Business English**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/orientation)
>
> **orientation**
> *noun* ​
>
> the type of interests, activities, or aims that an organization, business, or project has, or the act of giving attention
> to a particular thing:
>
> The company has adopted a new eco-friendly orientation.

M-W:

> **[orientation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/orientation)**
> *noun*
>
> **2 a** :  a usually general or lasting direction of thought, inclination, or interest
>
> The organization has a decidedly conservative orientation.
>
> Her later works were more introspective in orientation.

Answer (score 0):

**Ethos**

Ethos means ‘the characteristic spirit of a culture, era, or community as manifested in its beliefs and aspirations.’

From the greek ‘nature, disposition, customs’.

**‘I was thinking we will see a big difference in the type of pictures submitted between the two offices because of the difference in ethos between the two professional fields.’**

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/ethos